# Shared Library for Android and other Java project

Tags: android, class, project, shared

Hi I'm quite new at Android programming, and I am working on a project, which contain classic java part and Android part, and I need to share some classes between these 2 subprojects. I solved it that I have other project, where are the shared classes. 
Is this the best way ? Or is there better solution ?

Comment: Just use the other Java project as a library for the Android project no?

Comment: Use Gradle build system, it can manage such complex scenarios very easily!

Comment: Thanks I am using the first solution, Gradle looks really good, but now i don't have time to study it :)